# Planets Affected by FPS

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, game-physics, game-development

I'm trying to simulate **gravity** between two objects my **star** and my **planet**

but they are affected by the **FPS** as my FPS goes up and down the planets go faster and slower.

Where can I put the `Time.deltaTime` to fix this?

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Attractor : MonoBehaviour {
    
        const float G = 667.4f;
        public Rigidbody star;
        public Rigidbody planet;
        
        void Update(){
            Vector3 direction = star.position - planet.position;
            float distance = direction.magnitude;
    
            if (distance == 0f)
                return;
    
            float forceMagnitude = G * (star.mass * planet.mass) / Mathf.Pow(distance, 2);
            Vector3 force = direction.normalized * forceMagnitude;
    
            planet.AddForce(force);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move all physics code (in this case the `AddForce` and anything related) to `FixedUpdate()` rather than in `Update()`.

Answer (score 1):

As already mention, physics calculations should be on the `FixedUpdate()`

> Frame-rate independent MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate message for physics calculations.

Physics have their own *frame rate* but instead of variable `Time.deltaTime` they have fixed `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. Although when you use `AddForce()` in the `FixedUpdate()` you shouldn't multiply by the delta since its internally handled.

> ForceMode.Force: Interprets the input as force (measured in Newtons), and changes the velocity by the value of force * DT / mass.

You can learn more about [fixed update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) and [add force](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

Btw if you should multiply any values by `Time.deltaTime`, that would be any changing values per update, because what happens is that by multiplying by say `.1` you use a fraction of the value depending on how long was the last frame.

A quick frame has a small delta, a slower frame has a larger delta that results in a smaller fraction of the value for quicker frames and (...)

Hope that helps